# Get value from execl() call

Tags: c, unix, system-calls

I have made this program to run n other c programs. Suppose I want to execute three c programs :
1. Half of a Number
2. Double of a Number
3. Square of a Number
I am taking these three file names as the arguments from the command line and a Digit
Suppose I give the arguments : half square double 10
then the program execution will be double(square(half(10)))
So the output should be 50
I have made these three programs in such a way that these accept the number from the command line.
Now I am clueless that How can I return the value from that c programs which I have calculated . I have tried exit() and WEXITSTATUS(status) function but not getting the correct output

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<wait.h>
char* concat(char *s1, char *s2)
{
    char *result =(char *) malloc(strlen(s1)+strlen(s2)+1);
    strcpy(result, s1);
    strcat(result, s2);
    return result;
}
int main(int arg, char** args)
{
    int status,cpid;
    int n=arg;
    char* val = (args[n-1]);
    char* path="/home/naman/"; //This is the path where I have my all C programs
    if(arg<3)
        printf("Too less arguments\n");
    printf("Main program pid is : %d",(int)getpid());
    printf("\n");
    for(int i=1;i<n-1;i++)
    {
        if(fork())
        {
            wait(NULL);
            printf("Value return is : %d\n",WEXITSTATUS(status)); \\Not getting to correct value from that executed program

        }
        else
        {
            char* result=concat(path,args[i]);
            //printf("%s \n",result);
            execl(result,args[i],val,(char*)0);
            printf("I will never come here");
        }
    }
    printf("Value is : %d",atoi(val));
}
```

Comment: You might want to read [the `wait` manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait.2.html).

Comment: Compiler warnings are a great thing, too: *warning: 'status' may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]* (or *variable 'status' is uninitialized when used here [-Wuninitialized]*).

Comment: thanks.. that helped me... wait(&status) is the right way to get value... But it only passes last 8 bits of the status , So I can get only value till 256 ... Is there any way to get full status value?